# RealmList method - remove

Tags: android, realm

I use relationship between objects User:Task 1:N.

Method `realm.where(RealmUser.class).equalTo().findFirst()` returns managed RealmUser.

`RealmUser.getTasks()` return managed RealmList of RealmTasks.

What does remove method of RealmList? Remove object from Realm or only destroy reference (link)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Realm-Java 0.89.0+, `remove()` only destroys the link.

To delete an item, you must call `realmUser.deleteFromRealm()` inside a write transaction (or a `realmResults.deleteAllFromRealm()` on a RealmResults that contains the user)